# Formatting Issue JAVA

Tags: java, boolean, palindrome

I have to create a code with two methods that ask the user for a number and the program should tell whether it is a palidrome or not.

My code is the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args)  
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
      int value = scan.nextInt();

      int inversedNumber = reverse(value);
      System.out.println("Is value " +value+ " a palindrome?: " +isPalidrome(value));
   }
   public static int reverse(int number)
   {
      int reverse = 0;
      while( number != 0 )
      {
         reverse = reverse * 10;
         reverse = reverse + number%10;
         number = number/10;
      }
      return reverse;
   }

   public static boolean isPalidrome(int number)
   {
      boolean palidrome;
      if(inversedNumber == number)
         palidrome = true;
      else
         palidrome = false;

      return palidrome;
   }
}
```

But everytime I run it, I keep getting an error that tells me that `inversedNumber` in the method `isPalidrome` cannot be found. But it has been initialized in the main method. Should it not look for the initialization in the main method? Or my formating and/or logic are faulty.

Comment: No, it does not look in other methods for local variables. Local variables are, well, local. You may want to pass them around as parameters to method calls.

Comment: How are you able to compile this? Is inversedNumber also a global field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inversedNumber` is declared in `main()` and is not recognized in method `isPalidrome()` because it's not in the same [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

You can pass it to the method as follows:

call: `isPalidrome(value, inversedNumber)`

and change the method's signature to:

```
public static boolean isPalidrome(int number, int inversedNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE.** Local variable are only accessible within the block. `{}`

Because inversedNumber is local inside the main method and is only accessible within its body. You have two options to do the job.

1. Send the inversedNumber as a parameter to the method isPalendrom and change the signature of the method that expects two integers as below.

   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number, int inversedNumber)
   Then you call it inside main as `isPalindrome(value, inversedNumber)`
2. Make the variable inversedNumber global then you will be able to access it anywhere within the class.

   static int inversedNumber;

Then you can call it inside main and anywhere else as you are calling it now.

```
inversedNumber = reverse(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

`inversedNumber` is declare on different class hence other classes are not able to access it but only within its own class, you should pass it to the other class as code follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
      int value = scan.nextInt();

      int inversedNumber = reverse(value);
      System.out.println("Is value " +value+ " a palindrome?: " +isPalidrome(value,inversedNumber));
   }
   public static int reverse(int number)
   {
      int reverse = 0;
      while( number != 0 )
      {
         reverse = reverse * 10;
         reverse = reverse + number%10;
         number = number/10;
      }
      return reverse;
   }

   public static boolean isPalidrome(int number, int inversedNumber)
   {
      boolean palidrome;
      if(inversedNumber == number)
         palidrome = true;
      else
         palidrome = false;

      return palidrome;
   }
```

Besides, you can make `inversedNumber` as global variable too, then every classes are able to access it, you can declare it outside of the class as follow:

```
public static int inversedNumber;
```

Comment: While it's true that this should work, you should be providing reasoning behind your answer working rather than just solving it for them.